# Converting iPhone app to Universal Retaining Emulator Mode - Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode5, universal

I have an older nib-based iPhone project that I would like to make universal. To save time, since a redesign is approaching, I would like it to run as an iPhone app running on an iPad (emulation mode) but still be available on the app store as a universal binary.

I can easily generate an iPad-only binary that runs in emulation by right-clicking my iPhone target -> "duplicate target" -> "Duplicate and Transition to iPad". That's how I get an iPad target that runs in emulation mode (along with a folder full of iPad compatible nibs that are not used by the app - the new target uses the original iPhone nibs).

But how to submit this as a universal app? When I switch the target to universal it stops using emulation mode and looks for it's own set of nibs (which need considerable UI tweaking - even the auto-generated ones)

Anybody know any workarounds?

Comment: This makes no sense. If it's a universal app, it will NOT run in iPhone-compatibility mode on the iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that can't be done. Apple's definition of a Universal App is one that runs on both devices WITHOUT emulator mode on the iPad.

You can however duplicate your iPhone storyboard into an iPad storyboard and tweak your UI so that it resembles what you see in iPhone Emulator Mode. I've explained how to do this here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-convert-your-iphone-storyboard-into-an-ipad-storyboard/